# DICOM viewer for mac OS 10.6.8

Tags: osx, health, dicom

I'm desperately looking for a DICOM viewer (like OsiriX) that is compatible with my Mac OS 10.6.8.

I can't upgrade to the latest OS version and newer versions of OsiriX are only supported by OS 10.8 and up.